# Django, How to show and hide details of items in a ListView with jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I have a ListView in django which I'm trying to show/hide extra details for each item when a 'More info' button is pressed.
The issue is with trying to get a unique identifier for each item in the django template that javascript can act on to hide/show a specific item details rather than all of them. The javascript bit definitely isn't right.

```
<div class="quotes">
        {% for quote in quotes_results %}
          <div>
            <h3>{{ quote.supplierName }}</h3>
            <div>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-cta-primary" href="{% url 'users:profile' price_id=quote.priceId %}">Proceed</a>
            <button class="btn btn-cta-secondary" id="button">More Info</button>
          </div>
          <div class="til" id="til{{ quote.priceId }}" style="display:none">
            <p>test hide and show more details</p>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>

{% block inner_js %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#button').click(function (priceId) {
        $('#til' + priceId).toggle()
      })
    })

  </script>
{% endblock inner_js %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try it:

```
<!-- in html -->
<button class="btn btn-cta-secondary" data-id="{{ quote.priceId }}" >More Info</button>

  <!-- in js -->
  $('.btn-cta-secondary').click(function (e) {
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id')
    $('#til' + id).toggle()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks we both had a typo that stopped it from working. You needed $(this).data('id') and I had 'til' as the first part of the id but tried to target '#till'.  As gaetanoM said id's should be unique so I removed the `id="button" and targeted the css class which is also more specific that all of the buttons.   Additionally I went for  $(e.currentTarget).data('id') as this is more explicit and will work with arrow functions if needed.

Comment: Also I updated my template to start with the data hidden for the toggle.

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique. Hence, you need to change:

```
<button class="btn btn-cta-secondary" id="button">More Info</button>
```

to:

```
<button class="btn btn-cta-secondary" id="button{{ quote.priceId }}">More Info</button>
```

In order to toggle your **til** div you can select the **[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** div and then get the [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) div.

[[name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) can be used to select all buttons starting with...

```
$('[id^=button]').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('div').next('div.til').toggle();
})
```

The parameter of your event handler is the [event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and not the priceId.

```js
$('[id^=button]').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('div').next('div.til').toggle();
}).trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="quotes">
    <div>
        <h3>supplierName1</h3>
        <div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-cta-primary" href="{% url 'users:profile' price_id=quote.priceId %}">Proceed</a>
        <button class="btn btn-cta-secondary" id="buttonpriceId1">More Info</button>
    </div>
    <div class="til" id="tilpriceId1">
        <p>test hide and show more details1111111</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>supplierName2</h3>
        <div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-cta-primary" href="{% url 'users:profile' price_id=quote.priceId %}">Proceed</a>
        <button class="btn btn-cta-secondary" id="buttonpriceId2">More Info</button>
    </div>
    <div class="til" id="tilpriceId2">
        <p>test hide and show more details222222</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I didn't go for this in the end as it was too brittle and depended on the div being located next to the button.  Any change of layout would stop this working whereas Bear Brown's solution is more generally applicable.